# posting array of dictionaries with Restkit 0.20

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, restkit

Im having issues getting this to function correctly.

I have mapped the key value pairs of my JSON payload that I would like to inject into the request but I end up with a failure on each post.

The following lines show me creating the reqeust:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [WDMappingProvider createRegInitRequestTicketMapping];
    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:[requestMapping inverseMapping] objectClass:[WDTicketsModel class] rootKeyPath:nil];
[registrationManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

I then create my path to post to and put in the data to my post request:

```
//Make object from params
    WDRegistrationInitializeRequestModel *requestModel  = [[WDRegistrationInitializeRequestModel alloc] init];

    requestModel.eventID = [params objectForKey:@"eventID"];
    requestModel.arrayOfTicketDictionaries  = [params objectForKey:@"arrayOfTicketDictionaries"];

    NSString *postPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api/v1/registrations/initialize?eventid=%@", requestModel.eventID];

    //Post the object (aka the interest json payload)
    [registrationManager postObject:requestModel.arrayOfTicketDictionaries path:postPath parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result){ ...
```

At this point I always end up in the Failure block of the postObject method.

My mapping that is made by the [WDMappingProvider createRegInitRequestTicketMapping] looks like this:

```
+(RKObjectMapping *)createRegInitRequestTicketMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *regInitRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[WDTicketsModel class]];
    [regInitRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
     @{
        @"Quantity" : @"quantity",
        @"TicketID":@"mainID"
     }];


    return regInitRequestMapping;
}
```

The arrayOfTicketDictionaries looks like this:

```
[{"Quantity":1,"TicketID":1604},{"Quantity":1,"TicketID":1605},{"Quantity":1,"TicketID":1606}]
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're missing the `RKResponseDescriptor` part. Try adding this one:

```
// Anything in 2xx
NSIndexSet *statusCodes =
  RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
  [RKResponseDescriptor
   responseDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping
   method:RKRequestMethodAny
   pathPattern:nil
   keyPath:nil
   statusCodes:statusCodes];
[registrationManager addResponseDescriptor: responseDescriptor];
```

Comment: Can you please share the error you're getting? It would help to find your issue.